# keras - Layer model_131 expects 7 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm working on a text classification project with a dataframe that has 7 features (columns) and 1 label column (multi class ==> 6 possible labels overall)

All my data is text.

Since I wanted to keep my columns separated I ended up with the below code:

```
input_message = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(input_message)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_message = Model(inputs=input_message, outputs=x)

input_description = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(input_description)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_description = Model(inputs=input_description, outputs=x)

input_errors = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Embedding(2, 1)(input_errors)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_errors = Model(inputs=input_errors, outputs=x)

input_panics = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Embedding(2, 1)(input_panics)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_panics = Model(inputs=input_panics, outputs=x)

input_images = Input(shape=(2,))
x = Embedding(2, 1)(input_images)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_images = Model(inputs=input_images, outputs=x)

input_committer = Input(shape=(16,))
x = Embedding(16, 1)(input_committer)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_committer = Model(inputs=input_committer, outputs=x)

input_reporter = Input(shape=(6,))
x = Embedding(6, 1)(input_reporter)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_reporter = Model(inputs=input_reporter, outputs=x)

combined = Concatenate()([model_message.output, model_description.output, model_errors.output, 
                          model_panics.output, model_images.output, model_committer.output, model_reporter.output])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_message.input, model_description.input, 
                      model_errors.input, model_panics.input, model_images.input, 
                      model_committer.input, model_reporter.input], outputs=z)



model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

When running it, I'm getting the below error:

`ValueError: Layer model_131 expects 7 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 7) dtype=string>]`

below is the output of `model.summary()`:

```
Model: "model_131"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_128 (InputLayer)          [(None, 128)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_129 (InputLayer)          [(None, 128)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_99 (Embedding)        (None, 128, 64)      640000      input_128[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_100 (Embedding)       (None, 128, 64)      640000      input_129[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_70 (Flatten)            (None, 8192)         0           embedding_99[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_71 (Flatten)            (None, 8192)         0           embedding_100[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_130 (InputLayer)          [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_131 (InputLayer)          [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_132 (InputLayer)          [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_133 (InputLayer)          [(None, 16)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_134 (InputLayer)          [(None, 6)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_189 (Dense)               (None, 64)           524352      flatten_70[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_192 (Dense)               (None, 64)           524352      flatten_71[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_101 (Embedding)       (None, 2, 1)         2           input_130[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_102 (Embedding)       (None, 2, 1)         2           input_131[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_103 (Embedding)       (None, 2, 1)         2           input_132[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_104 (Embedding)       (None, 16, 1)        16          input_133[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_105 (Embedding)       (None, 6, 1)         6           input_134[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_190 (Dense)               (None, 32)           2080        dense_189[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_193 (Dense)               (None, 32)           2080        dense_192[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_72 (Flatten)            (None, 2)            0           embedding_101[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_73 (Flatten)            (None, 2)            0           embedding_102[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_74 (Flatten)            (None, 2)            0           embedding_103[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_75 (Flatten)            (None, 16)           0           embedding_104[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_76 (Flatten)            (None, 6)            0           embedding_105[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_191 (Dense)               (None, 4)            132         dense_190[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_194 (Dense)               (None, 4)            132         dense_193[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_195 (Dense)               (None, 1)            3           flatten_72[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_196 (Dense)               (None, 1)            3           flatten_73[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_197 (Dense)               (None, 1)            3           flatten_74[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_198 (Dense)               (None, 1)            17          flatten_75[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_199 (Dense)               (None, 1)            7           flatten_76[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_17 (Concatenate)    (None, 13)           0           dense_191[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_194[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_195[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_196[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_197[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_198[0][0]                  
                                                                 dense_199[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_200 (Dense)               (None, 6)            84          concatenate_17[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,333,273
Trainable params: 2,333,273
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/2
```

I wasn't able to understand what it means.

I do understand that the model expects 7 inputs (they're also being passed to it), so why it claims to only receive 1?

BTW the output of `X_train.shape` is `(11652, 7)`

**Updating the code section per comments discussion:**

So I've decreased the number of layers to 2 and ended up with this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, Concatenate, Flatten
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer as Tok
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

vocab_size = 1000
embedding_dim = 16
max_length = 128
trunc_type='post'
padding_type='post'
oov_tok = "<OOV>"


# prepare input data
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = OrdinalEncoder()
    oe.fit(X_train)
    X_train_enc = oe.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.fit_transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc
 
# prepare free text input
def prepare_free_text_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    training_sentences = X_train['message'] + ' ' + X_train['description']
    testing_sentences = X_test['message'] + ' ' + X_test['description']
    tokenizer = Tok(num_words=vocab_size, oov_token=oov_tok)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_sentences)
    word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    
    training_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_sentences)
    training_padded = pad_sequences(training_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
    
    testing_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(testing_sentences)
    testing_padded = pad_sequences(testing_sequences, maxlen=max_length, padding=padding_type, truncating=trunc_type)
    return training_padded, testing_padded
    
    
# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
 

# prepare free_text input data
X_train_tokenized, X_test_tokenized = prepare_free_text_inputs(X_train, X_test)

# prepare categorical input data
X_train_ord, X_test_ord = prepare_inputs(X_train.iloc[:, 2:], X_test.iloc[:, 2:])

X_train_enc = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_train_tokenized), pd.DataFrame(X_train_ord)], axis=1)
X_test_enc = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_test_tokenized), pd.DataFrame(X_test_ord)], axis=1)

# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)

print('Train', X_train_enc.shape, y_train_enc.shape)
print('Test', X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

input_free_text = Input(shape=(128,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, 64)(input_free_text)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
model_free_text = Model(inputs=input_free_text, outputs=x)

input_categorical = Input(shape=(5,))
x = Embedding(5, 1)(input_categorical)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="relu")(x)
model_categorical = Model(inputs=input_categorical, outputs=x)

combined = Concatenate()([model_free_text.output, model_categorical.output])

z = Dense(6, activation='softmax')(combined)
model = Model(inputs=[model_free_text.input, model_categorical.input], outputs=z)


model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

model.summary()
keras.utils.plot_model(model, "model.png", show_shapes=True)
history = model.fit(y_train_enc, y_train_enc, batch_size=64, epochs=2, validation_split=0.2)
```

Still got similar error:

`ValueError: Layer model_235 expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>]`

Comment: have you tried to reshape the inputs and concatenate along an axis?

Comment: @B.Kocis no. can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: You have 7 input layers. So, `x_train` should contain your 7 inputs data. Add the definition of `x_train` into your question. The error says `x_train` provides just 1 input data.

Comment: @Kaveh the output of `X_train.shape` is `(11652, 7)` (updated the question as well)

Comment: it expects the first dimension as 7

Comment: @Kaveh not sure why, I'm having 7 columns with 11652 rows dataframe. How should I approach it then?

Comment: Why did you define 7 input layers? Your input layers have different shapes. first one (0,128), the other (none,2), and (none, 16). So, you should pass each layer the input it expects. If you have 11652 samples with 7 columns in dataframe, you don't need 7 input layer. you need 1 input layer with `input_shape=(7,)` argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235155/discussion-between-ben-and-kaveh).

Comment: @Kaveh I was under the impression that each column should be treated differently as I wanted each to be processed in a different manner.
Otherwise, how's that any different than just uniting all columns to a single one (like in sequential model)?
I guess I'm missing something very basic.
Isn't that my use case here?

Comment: @Kaveh Updated the question with the new code per our discussion - can you take a look and let me know what am I (still) missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question then:

It turns out that I didn't handle the `fit` model method correctly.
I wasn't aware it can also get multiple inputs.
This is what I've ended up doing (based on the updated question code):

```
history = model.fit(x=[X_train_tokenized, X_train_ord], y=y_train_enc, 
                    validation_data=([X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y_test_enc), 
                    batch_size=64, epochs=10)

test_scores = model.evaluate(x=[X_test_tokenized, X_test_ord], y=y_test_enc, verbose=0)
```